# Detecting overshoot lines in road network (flyovers, over/underpasses) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, network

I need to find ways to detect overshoot lines (such as flyovers, over/underpasses) in road network to validate topological connections.

I suppose there are two approaches; the one is "detecting overshoot links" and another is "generating nodes at the intersection of overshoot links" as illustrated below. I think the latter may be easier.

[image]

I think `detect dangles in topology checker` may be one of the solutions, but as my network contains huge number of centroids, this function generates lots of points which are topologically correct.
I also found a similar question at [Finding intersection topology errors in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272602) but it requires a manual process. I want to avoid a complicated process as I have several road networks which requires the same validation again and again.

Is there a more efficient way to generate nodes on the overshoot lines?

Comment: You might look at the v.clean tool in the GRASS section of the Processing Toolbox.  Perhaps the SAGA split lines with lines is worth a look.